# Moving Highest Values of a Column (and Its associated Columns) to Sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Data - Different Delivered Dates and No. of Items to be delivered on the respective day. But I want to move only the highest values of a column P2:P585 (And Associated columns A,B,C...O,P)

**Date of Delivery**        **No.of Products to be Delivered**
17/03/2017                        - 10
20/03/2017                        - 2
21/03/2017                        - 21
23/03/2017                        - 4
24/03/2017                        - 14
27/03/2017                        - 12
28/03/2017                        - 26
03/04/2017                        - 10

For Example: on 17.03.2017, I have 94 Items after filtering. But I want to move only the Highest 10 Items  to Sheet2. On 20.03.17, I have 85 Items, BuT I want move only Highest 2 values among 85 Items available in this day. This has to be done seriously for many dates till end of year and different qty on each date. So, my programm should contain the cell reference for Delivery date and Qty, So that I can use for N no. of datas.. Sorting is done already. Only the command to move given no. of qty for each delivery date is required. Some could help with ideas.?

```
Sub Filter_RPCALC()

'Calculation of Date Diff.
Range("N2").Formula = "=DAYS($A$590,D2)"
Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N585"), Type:=xlFillDefault

'Calculation of Rp
Dim var1 As Variant, var2 As Variant, var3 As Variant
Dim Rp As Variant
Dim i As Long
var1 = Range("M2:M585").Value
var2 = Range("02:0585").Value
var3 = Range("L2:L585").Value
Rp = var1
For i = LBound(Rp, 1) To UBound(Rp, 1)
    Rp(i, 1) = var1(i, 1) * var2(i, 1) + var3(i, 1)
Next i
Range("P2:P585").Value = Rp

'Filter the coils for Deliver Date
ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1:$G$585").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(Range("A590"))

'Sorting High to low of Rp
Range("A2:P585").Sort _
Key1:=Range("P2:P585"), Order1:=xlDescending

End Sub
```

Comment: The whole row or just the value of Column P?

Comment: The whole Row. But the input for no. of Highest value rows to be mvoed should be the cell value. i.e If I give 10 in cell B590. It should move 10 items with max. values among all. If I cell value og B590 is 2. It should move First 2 Highest items to sheet2

Comment: When someone says **move** and doesn't show any code that attempts the operation, I tend to think they actually mean **copy**.

Comment: What if there is a tie for the 10th largest?

Comment: Jeeped. Actually it is copy. But the source data should be erased or deleted in sheet1

Comment: Then it should denote an error code. Have to write  it in program

Answer (score 1):

Assuming headers exist in row 1, we'll take a look at your top 10 items (sorted decended so highest value at the top):

```
With Sheets("Source")
    .Range(.Rows(1),.Rows(11)).Cut Sheets("Destination").Cells(1,1)
    .Range(.Rows(2),.Rows(11)).Delete
End With
```

Moves the data and then removes the, now, blank rows.

Comment: If your destination sheet is a tally page, you will need to find the last row of the new sheet each time you paste the highest values to said sheet.

Comment: But you had mentioned the row no.s directly as 1 and 11. But actually qty 10 No.s to be moved will be mentioned in a cell namely B590. Will thise code automatically choose Row values to b/w 1 and 11. May be If give value of B590 as 2, then automatically to b/w, 1 and 3..?

Comment: with this code,I think I have to change the programm manually everytime, whenever my shipping qty change in cell B590. For example 5 instead of 10. Is there some way it will  automatically update or calculate the range of rows to move based on input in cell  B590.?

Comment: @sheela Yes you can do that, though you would need to declare it as a variable and utilize that in the range.  E.g., Dim r as Long, r = Cells(590,"B").Value which would work if ONLY the row were stored in B590.  You would need to update your question with that additional information if this isn't sufficient information, since you can't adequately display the information in the comments section.

Comment: May be then I will explain the need more clearly in a new quesion.

Answer (score 1):

This should do.

```
Sub Filter_RPCALC()
    Dim var1 As Variant, var2 As Variant, var3 As Variant, Rp As Variant
    Dim philters As Variant, p As Long, qtys As Variant
    Dim i As Long, f As Long, lr As Long, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        lr = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row)
        'Calculation of Date Diff.
        .Range(.Cells(2, "N"), .Cells(lr, "N")).Formula = "=DAYS($A$590,D2)"

        'Calculation of Rp
        var1 = .Range("M2:M" & lr).Value
        var2 = .Range("O2:O" & lr).Value
        var3 = .Range("L2:L" & lr).Value
        Rp = var1
        For i = LBound(Rp, 1) To UBound(Rp, 1)
            Rp(i, 1) = var1(i, 1) * var2(i, 1) + var3(i, 1)
        Next i
        .Range("P2").Resize(UBound(Rp, 1), UBound(Rp, 2)) = Rp

        philters = Array(DateSerial(2017, 3, 17), 10, DateSerial(2017, 3, 20), 2, _
                         DateSerial(2017, 3, 21), 21, DateSerial(2017, 3, 23), 4, _
                         DateSerial(2017, 3, 24), 14, DateSerial(2017, 3, 27), 12, _
                         DateSerial(2017, 3, 28), 26, DateSerial(2017, 4, 3), 10)
        'Filter the coils for Deliver Date
        With .Range("A1:P" & lr)
            For p = LBound(philters) To UBound(philters) Step 2
                .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=philters(p)
                ReDim qtys(philters(p + 1))
                For i = LBound(qtys) To UBound(qtys)
                    qtys(i) = Application.Aggregate(14, 7, .Columns(2), i + 1)
                Next i
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=qtys, operation:=xlFilterValues
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                        Destination:=ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                End With
            Next p

            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(16), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                       Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes

        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Haloo Jeeped, Thanks for the code. But I am getting an error - 'Run Time Error 13' - Type match - in the Program Line : Rp(i, 1) = var1(i, 1) * var2(i, 1) + var3(i, 1)

Comment: Considering that was one of the lines of code that I did not change from your original, I really cannot give you an explanation. I would however look for worksheet error codes in those 4 ranges.